# sort array of numeric strings with Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
_.sortBy(arrData, "rhid");
```

This code sorts array but as the values of field "rhid" are strings the order is messed up.
How can i sort as if "rhid" where int field.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`sortBy` can be used with a function instead of a property name.

```
_.sortBy(arrData, function (obj) {
    return parseInt(obj.rhid, 10);
});
```

Comment: How can I sort by more than two fields and sort by desc with this implementation?

Comment: @GunasekaranR - in that case you can use this: 

    sortBy(arrData, [function(obj) {
        return parseInt(obj.field1);
        }, function(obj) {
        return parseInt(obj.field2);
    }]);

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved using arrow notation like:

```
_.sortBy(arrData, (obj) => parseInt(obj.val, 10));
```

If you want to do more than one field like @GunasekaranR asked, you can also do it with arrow notation:

```
_.sortBy(arrData, [
  (obj) => parseInt(obj.first_val, 10),
  (obj) => parseInt(obj.second_val, 10)
]);
```

The second way uses `first_val` as the main sorting object, with `second_val` being the tie breaker.

Answer (score 0):

if rhid is number then you can do like this

```
orderBy(
      arrData,
      function (o) {
        return new Number(o.rhid);
      },
      ["asc"]
    ),
```

mentioned [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2174#issuecomment-444388766)