# How to sort a numeric string field with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
  sortedDatawithfield = (field, data) => {
    let res = _.sortBy(data, [field]);
    return res
  } 



  data = [
    {
      "cpm": "9.839933",
      "ctr": "8.508846",
      "cpc": "0.115644",
      "spend": "11.68",
      "date_start": "2020-03-18",
      "date_stop": "2020-03-18",
      "index": 19
    },
    {
      "cpm": "11.440139",
      "ctr": "8.849046",
      "cpc": "0.129281",
      "spend": "19.78",
      "date_start": "2020-03-17",
      "date_stop": "2020-03-17",
      "index": 18
    },
    {
      "cpm": "12.720915",
      "ctr": "8.518754",
      "cpc": "0.149328",
      "spend": "20.01",
      "date_start": "2020-03-16",
      "date_stop": "2020-03-16",
      "index": 17
    },
    {
      "cpm": "9.601182",
      "ctr": "6.351551",
      "cpc": "0.151163",
      "spend": "19.5",
      "date_start": "2020-03-22",
      "date_stop": "2020-03-22",
      "index": 21
    }
  ]


  res = this.sortedDatawithfield("cpc", data)
  console.log(res)
```

Here i am trying to sort "cpc" field using lodash.

above is the function i have written is not working properly.
I think because it is in a numeric string format .

Is there any way to sort with numeric string using lodash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724034/sort-array-of-numeric-strings-with-lodash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change :

```
this.sortedDatawithfield("cpc", data)
```

...to:

```
this.sortedDatawithfield(item => parseFloat(item.cpc), data)
```

This should work since [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy) accepts selector functions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `lodash`, you can use java script inbuilt `sort` function.

```js
const data = [{
    "cpm": "9.839933",
    "ctr": "8.508846",
    "cpc": "0.115644",
    "spend": "11.68",
    "date_start": "2020-03-18",
    "date_stop": "2020-03-18",
    "index": 19
  },
  {
    "cpm": "11.440139",
    "ctr": "8.849046",
    "cpc": "0.129281",
    "spend": "19.78",
    "date_start": "2020-03-17",
    "date_stop": "2020-03-17",
    "index": 18
  },
  {
    "cpm": "12.720915",
    "ctr": "8.518754",
    "cpc": "0.149328",
    "spend": "20.01",
    "date_start": "2020-03-16",
    "date_stop": "2020-03-16",
    "index": 17
  },
  {
    "cpm": "9.601182",
    "ctr": "6.351551",
    "cpc": "0.151163",
    "spend": "19.5",
    "date_start": "2020-03-22",
    "date_stop": "2020-03-22",
    "index": 21
  }
];

const output = data.sort(({
  cpc: firstCpc,
  cpc: secondCpc
}) => Number(firstCpc) - Number(secondCpc));
console.log(output);
```